# get the number of runnable story files java

Tags: java, jbehave

Is there any way to get the number of all step implementations of the stories?
I would like to create a progress bar, but i have to know the number of runnable test cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, solved. I/You don't have to count the steps, just simply put the control of the progress bar's increase to a @AfterScenario "step", and it will count in all of the skipped test cases and working charming with any number of steps.